# Difference between polyint() and int()

Tags: matlab

I can't understand the difference between `polyint()` and `int()` ..
Which amongst these must I use to integrate a polynomial? Kindly help...

Comment: `int` is for symbolic.  See also: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/analytic-solution-to-integral-of-polynomial.html

Answer (score 0):

`polyint()` is related only to polynomials. It returns a coeficients of polynomials which is an antiderivative of the input polynomial. `int()` is a function for symbolic integration of any function. It is more general.